# How do I use my host server info instead of localhost on XAMPP?

Tags: php, xampp, hosting

I have been building a website with PHP functionality in XAMPP, and everything works perfectly within the localhost. Although, I know that in order to have the same functionality on a live hosted server I will need to change the server info in my config.php file that is used:

```
<?php
    define('ROOT_URL', 'http://localhost/newkellumws/');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASS', 'austink01');
    define('DB_NAME', 'kellumws');
```

I've tried changing the DB_HOST to my hosting profile's nameserver, but that did not work. Any help is much appreciated and thank you for your time. I apologize if the is a newbie question...

Comment: We can't possibly answer this question. You need to get the database server's hostname from your provider.

Comment: I thought the database server's hostname would be my hosting profile's nameserver, but i tried that as DB_USER and it still wasn't connecting.

Comment: Are you runing the code in your computer or have you uploaded to the server? If you are runing it localy, your hosting probably has the database port closed to the public, so you will be unable to connect

Comment: I have run the code locally on my computer and all works fine, but when i upload the files to my host server the database doesn't connect. I changed the DB_HOST to my host server name and uploaded the files to the host server and it still doesn't connect.

Comment: You probably need to change things like account user, password and database name as well. But those are things we cannot help with, you will need to ask your hosting provider...

Comment: Have you tried `localhost`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are also moving the site as well the hostname will remain as localhost (as is the case with most shared hosting)

Assuming it's cPanel hosting you will first need to create the database.
You can then create an SQL account and grant it access to the DB (recommended) or use your cPanel credentials (Not Recommended)

So your config would look something like this:

```
define('ROOT_URL', 'http://example.com/newkellumws/');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); // Website and SQL ruinning on the same server
define('DB_USER', 'exampl_kellumws');
define('DB_PASS', 'aBc*63oie8wfq');
define('DB_NAME', 'exampl_kellumws');
```

See https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/68Docs/MySQL+Databases

if the site is still going to be run via XAMPP  (For whatever reason) you would also need to allow Remote MySQL

See https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/68Docs/Remote+MySQL

So your config would instead look something like this:

```
define('ROOT_URL', 'http://example.com/newkellumws/');
define('DB_HOST', 'c01.example.host'); //Address the SQL Server
define('DB_USER', 'exampl_kellumws');
define('DB_PASS', 'aBc*63oie8wfq');
define('DB_NAME', 'exampl_kellumws');
```

If you still have issues, contact your hosting provider as they will know the server setup and requirements.

You can also create testConnection.php with the following to help diagnose errors

```
<?php
require_once('path/to/file/with/config.php');
//Step-1 : Create a database connection
$connection=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
if(!$connection) {
    die(“Database Connection error: ” . mysql_error());
}
//Step-2 : Select a database to use
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connection);
if(!$db) {
    die(“Database Selection error” . mysql_error());
}
echo('Connected to Database');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server infos and local `XAMP` are different localhost works like following.
You dont need url part as its localhost/your_folder

```
<?php
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASS', ''); //Xamp doesnt have a password for root as default leave it empty if you didnt set one.
    define('DB_NAME', 'kellumws');
    define('PORT', '3306');
```

latest version of `XAMP` request port for `MySql` port, add it into your connection. mostly its 3306 as default but sometimes it changes to 3307 or 3308 because of `mariaDB` comes as default you can see real path on `XAMP` tool.

Than just call http://localhost/newkellumws/ if you created a folder.